# Loading managed Windows PowerShell failed with error 80070002

Tags: 64-bit, crash, powershell

I get an error when I try to run PowerShell:

`Internal Windows PowerShell error. Loading managed Windows PowerShell failed with error 80070002.`

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit). This error occurs whether I start PowerShell from the command line or from the start menu shortcut. Running as administrator does not solve the issue either.

How do I fix this problem, so that I can use PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used my laptop's system recovery feature to reinstall Windows, and then I was able to use PowerShell just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is considerably old but since I also had this problem, you need to check to see if you have a powershell.exe.config or a powershell_ise.exe.config file in the ...\v1.0\ directory, rename/delete those files or completely patch the system (make sure there are no pending patches or reboots) and the problem should resolve itself:

http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/689952/resolved-user-error-powershell-exe-fails-to-start-after-wmf-3-0-ctp1-is-installed#tabs

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by missing

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll
```

Which should be at

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost
```

It can be restored reinstalling *Windows Management Framework*

[PowerShell failed with error 80070002 - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/562886)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling powershell? This sounds like a corrupted install.

Comment: There is no way to reinstall PowerShell on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought you're using Windows XP... my fault.